# Nginx 502 Error on streaming from AWS S3 bucket using Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

`[error] 788704#788704: *2853 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ...., server: ....., request: "GET /api/stream?video_url=https://crowplus-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/Crow+Trailer.mp4.mp4 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/stream?video_url=https://crowplus-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/Crow+T` is the nginx error I am getting whenever I call the endpoint displaying error 502

This is the server configuration
`  location / {

```
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
    proxy_buffering off;
```

}`

and the node js code
`let stream = StripeStreamMovie(video_key)

```
        stream.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('Error streaming video');
        });

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');

        stream.pipe(res);`
```

`const StripeStreamMovie = (videoKey) => {

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: videoKey,
};

const stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

return stream
```

}`

[image: Image of the error screen]

Note: other endpoints that are not stream endpoints are working fine and the stream is also working in my local environment as shown below
[image: streaming in my local environment]

I have tried different approaches to reconfigure the Nginx but i'm still getting the same error. I want to use the endpoint as source url in video players to stream videos from AWS S3 bucket in bits.